# How to solve a Sturm-Louiville Problem with nonhomogeneous BCs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

I'm trying to solve the following steady-state problem:

> $$\nabla^2 u = 0 , \ \ \ (x,y,z) \in [0,\ 2]^3$$
>
> Insulated in the faces with $x=0,y=2$. Kept at $0º$C on the faces with $x=2,z=0$. And kept at $T_0$ when $y=0$. It also satisfies Newtons Law of Cooling on the other face ($z=2$) that is
>
> $$-ku_z(x,y,z) = hu(x,y,z) \ \ \ \ h>0, \ \ k>0$$

We now perform separation of variables: $u(x,y,z) = X(x)Y(y)Z(z)$

So our PDE becomes $$YZX^" + XZY^" + XYZ^" = 0$$ or

$$ \frac{X^"}{X} = -\frac{Y^"}{Y} - \frac{Z^"}{Z} = - \mu $$

Then
$$ \frac{Y^"}{Y} + \frac{Z^"}{Z} =  \mu  \iff \frac{Y^"}{Y} = \mu - \frac{Z^"}{Z} = - \lambda $$

From here, the following problem arises:
$$Y"(y) + \lambda Y = 0; \ \ Y(0) = T_0 ; \ \ Y´(2) = 0$$

I've tried using the Rayleigh quotient to prove that the eigenvalues are positive, but it relies on the sign of $Y'(0)$ which we don't know.

By performing the usual discussing on the values of $\lambda$ ($0, \ <0, \ >0)$ I get that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for all those cases, which doesn't really make sense since this eigenvalue problem comes up after separation of variables in solving Laplace's equation in a cube. So there should be only one case (or maybe two, with the case $\lambda=0$).

Comment: What's an eigenvalue in this setting? Is it a value of $\lambda$ such that there are infinitely many solutions? I ask because here the differential operator isn't being defined on a vector space so it does not make strict sense to speak of an eigenvalue. Or is it just a value of $\lambda$ such that there are *any* solutions?

Comment: It is, we obtain a sequence of values $\lambda_n$ and eigenfunctions $Y_n$ that solve the Sturm-Luoiville problem.

Comment: In what sense are they eigenvalues and eigenfunctions? Again, normally we say an eigenvalue is a property of a linear operator defined on a vector space, so that eigenvectors (here eigenfunctions) are only determined up to nonzero scalar multiples. Here the domain of the problem isn't a vector space, so it doesn't make strict sense to speak of eigenvalues. This doesn't mean it's nonsense, only that you need to be careful about what you mean by "eigenvalue" since what you mean is not what people normally mean by that word.

Comment: And I don't just say this to be pedantic, I say this because I suspect this is part of what is confusing you. For example, as Robert Israel already pointed out, because negative values of $\lambda$ do *not* correspond to eigenvalues of the associated problem with homogeneous BCs, the problem has unique solutions for $\lambda<0$.

Comment: My linear operator is the Laplacian. This SL problem appears after performing separation of variables for $u(x,y,z)$ in the the PDE $\nabla^2 u = 0$, and equalling the different ODEs to a constant. I honestly don't understand what you're really trying to say...

Comment: Let me be a bit more direct since you don't seem to understand my question (which is about your use of nonstandard terminology). Normally, we talk about eigenvalues and eigenvectors for linear operators defined on vector spaces. Inhomogeneous problems don't have solutions that form vector spaces, so the concept of eigenvalues and eigenvectors are not immediately applicable. However, we apply the *concept* of eigenvalues and eigenvectors to an inhomogeneous problem *through* the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the homogeneous problem.

Comment: (Cont.) Namely, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue then to any particular solution to the inhomogeneous problem you can add a corresponding eigenfunction and get another solution. If $\lambda$ is *not* an eigenvalue of the homogeneous problem then the solution, if it exists, is unique (because if there were two then the difference would be an eigenfunction of the homogeneous problem). Under some assumptions we can additionally use the Fredholm alternative to conclude that a solution to the inhomogenous problem always exists when $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue.

Comment: Of course I am not the word police, so if you want to say that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the inhomogenous problem if at least one nonzero solution exists, then I won't try to stop you. But I will inform you that confusion will ensue when you communicate with others. And I suspect your entire source of confusion is this terminology conflict (you don't expect there to be a continuum of eigenvalues, and there isn't...in the normal sense of the word).

Comment: The usual approach is to use the homogeneous boundary conditions first, to get a basis of solutions, then take a linear combination of those to match the non-homogeneous boundary condition (in this case $u(x,0,z)=T_0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution of $Y'' + \lambda Y = 0$ for $\lambda < 0$ is $c_1 \exp(\sqrt{-\lambda} y) + c_2 \exp(-\sqrt{-\lambda} y)$.  The condition $Y'(2) = 0$
corresponds to $c_2 =  c_1 \exp(4 \sqrt{-\lambda})$, and then $Y(0) =  c_1 (1 + \exp(4 \sqrt{-\lambda}))$.
Thus if $\lambda < 0$, for every $T_0$ there is a unique solution to your boundary value problem.

Comment: Why $\lambda <0$? if $\lambda = 0$, $Y = c_1y + c_2; \ then Y'(2) = c_1 = 0$ and $Y(0) = T_0 = c_2$ therefore $Y_0 = 1$ is an eigenfunction and $\lambda_0 = 0$ an eigenvalue

Comment: In the case $\lambda = 0$, there is again a unique solution.  I wouldn't call that an eigenvalue.  This is the analogue of the solution $Y=0$ in the homogeneous case.  For an eigenvalue the solution is not unique.